# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am getting this error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword while performing a transaction.
Below is my JPQL query please let me know if there is any issues.

@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Employee e SET e.salary=:salary where e.name=:name and e.salary < :salary")
void updateSalary(@Param("salary") Integer salary, @Param("name") String name);

changed from "set" to "SET" but it didn't still work.